# Smart pointers and cache/memory locality

Tags: c++11, pointers, vector, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I am trying to understand smart pointers in context of locality. I have looked at several questions here on S/O regarding having a `std::vector` of `MyObject`s and a `std::vector` of smart pointers (`shared_ptr`/`unique_ptr`) to `MyObject`s.

What I haven't found the answer to is, if I have a vector of 1000 smart pointers to `MyObject`s (using `make_shared`/`make_unique`), are the objects themselves stored in random locations in memory and the smart pointers stored in a contiguous block of memory in the vector, or are the pointers and the object both stored in the contiguous block of memory in the vector?

Answer (score 0):

At least the elements in a vector are guaranteed to be stored contiguously. This is per the recent C++ standards.

The objects pointed to by the smart pointer are stored somewhere else. It will depend on the memory manager where your object will end up.

If you have a choice, it might be better (and faster) to store the objects directly into the vector. A pointer adds an extra layer of indirection which could slow your program down.

Comment: How would one go about making sure the objects pointed to by the smart pointer are also stored in some contiguous block of memory or as close as possible? Does I need to write my own allocator?

Comment: Yes, you would have to do something like that indeed.
But that starts to sound like reinventing the vector class itself.

Could you explain what you are actually trying to achieve?
Why not simply push all your objects to the vector?

Comment: Faster iteration and since the objects stored are big it's much better to have a vector of pointers to the object than the object itself since its expensive to copy/move the objects as the vector grows and well, the smart pointers take care of managing the object's lifetime. @E. Van Putten

Comment: I have implemented my own vector class and I use std::allocator to allocate(), construct() and deallocate() objects. I am not sure how to make it store the objects pointed to by the smart pointer also in a contiguous block. It's the same with std::vector, so I believe something could be done that can be used with both vector implementations.

Comment: Ah, I see. And does the data itself change?

Why not run some benchmarks on various implementations

Comment: Yes, the data gets changed by the user on demand. @E. van Putten

Comment: Just came across this link: http://sysrun.haifa.il.ibm.com/hrl/ISMM2009/present/ISMM09_13.pdf

Amongst others, they compare a number of allocators.